# If statement is triggered and then exits the if statement before the If -And statement gets triggered

Tags: powershell

So currently working on a new staff script and im slightly confused as to why the If statement exits once it returns true

I would expect it to continue with the If statement until the end to see if it matched any others better. Can someone explain why it works this way (I'm guessing for performance)

I have resolved my issue by re-arranging the order of the If statement, but I was wondering if there was a better or more elegant way to go about this?

So an example is below:
before I put the last ElseIf at the bottom any member of staff from school XX was getting put into the staff OU even if their Department was one of those listed in the If -AND statements

```bsh
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC' -And $Department -eq 'IT Staff'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=IT Services,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC' -And $Department -eq 'ILS Staff'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=Resources,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC' -And $Department -eq 'DATA Staff'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=Data,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC' -And $Department -eq 'Facilities Staff'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=Estates & Facilities,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC' -And $Department -eq 'Catering Staff'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=Events & Catering,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
    ElseIf ($school -eq 'KCC'){
    [STRING]$MiddleOU = 'OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    [STRING]$HomeDirectory = ('\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\'+ $SamAccountName)
    }
```

Comment: Use `switch` or even better hashtables. This will make the script much simpler and more readable.

Comment: thought that might be the answer, im used to Python where they don't exist...thanks

Comment: Although Python doesn't have `switch` it has dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness and as a reference to a more preferable way for implementing of such constructions.

```
$dom="\\ad.esw.org.uk"
$deptdata=@(
   @{dept='IT Staff'; ou='OU=IT Services,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='; homedir="$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"},
   @{dept='ILS Staff'; ou='OU=Resources,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='; homedir="$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"},
   @{dept='DATA Staff'; ou='OU=Data,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='; homedir="$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"},
   @{dept='Facilities Staff'; ou='OU=Estates & Facilities,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='; homedir="$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"},
   @{dept='Catering Staff'; ou='OU=Events & Catering,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='; homedir="$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"}
)

If ($school -eq 'KCC'){

   $MiddleOU = 'OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
   $HomeDirectory = ("$dom\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName")

    $deptdata | where {$_.dept -eq $Department} | foreach {
      $MiddleOU = $_.ou
      $HomeDirectory = $_.homedir
    }
}
```

As a further improvement the data could be stored in an external JSON/XML file.

Answer (score 2):

`if/elseif` doesn't work the way you are hoping.  It will stop looking after it makes a valid match.  It assesses each case in isolation and won't look for a 'better' match unless the current case doesn't match.

This isn't for performance optimisation, but is standard behaviour in various programming languages, not just PowerShell.

Get more details in the official documentation: [about_If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-6)

Comment: you learn something every day...guess I've never tried to implement this before, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I look at this as a matter of programming logic.  I've removed some unnecessary '[string]'s and '()'s.  Maybe I don't understand the problem.  Doesn't putting the generic match last fix the problem?  This is very typical program logic.  Too bad $Department and the $MiddleOU use different terms.

```
if ($school -eq 'KCC) {
    $HomeDirectory = "\\ad.esw.org.uk\KCC\StaffUsers\$SamAccountName"

    If ($Department -eq 'IT Staff'){
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=IT Services,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
    ElseIf ($Department -eq 'ILS Staff'){
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=Resources,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
    ElseIf ($Department -eq 'DATA Staff'){
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=Data,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
    ElseIf ($Department -eq 'Facilities Staff'){
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=Estates & Facilities,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
    ElseIf ($Department -eq 'Catering Staff'){
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=Events & Catering,OU=Business Managment,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
    Else {
      $MiddleOU = 'OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU='
    }
}
```